# Oracle Database Change Notifications only sent every 15 minutes

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, eclipselink

I'm registering a listener for Oracle Database Change Notifications (using the EclipseLink implementation of JPA, Oracle 11.2.0.3, Oracle JDBC thin driver 11.2.0.4):

```
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin(); // otherwise we cannot unwrap the Connection from the entityManager
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        DatabaseChangeRegistration databaseChangeRegistration = ((OracleConnection)entityManager.unwrap(Connection.class)).registerDatabaseChangeNotification(properties);
        databaseChangeRegistration.addListener(this);

        //now you need to add whatever tables you want to monitor
        try (Statement stmt = entityManager.unwrap(Connection.class).createStatement()) {
            //associate the statement with the registration:
            ((OracleStatement) stmt).setDatabaseChangeRegistration(databaseChangeRegistration); //look up the documentation to this method [http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleStatement.html#setDatabaseChangeRegistration_oracle_jdbc_dcn_DatabaseChangeRegistration_]
            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MY_MONITORED_TABLE WHERE ROWNUM=1")) { //you have to execute the query to link it to the statement for it to be monitored
                while (rs.next()) {
                    //..do sth with the results if interested...
                }
            }
        }
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

I'm getting notifications, but all of them in one chunk every 15 minutes. The 15 minutes are based on absolute time, regardless of when I start listening. It seems like the job sending the notifications only runs at a fixed interval of 15 minutes on the server.

If I register a PL/SQL procedure directly on the server to receive notifications, the notifications are instant.

What options do I have, to reduce the interval? I'm aiming for instant or every few seconds.

Comment: You are doing this within a transaction, could it be that transaction isolation is preventing you from seeing changes until the transaction times out?  Have you seen EclipseLink's DCN support and how it adds a listener:  https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/DatabaseEvents  You might be better off using a OracleChangeNotificationListener subclass to do what you want during the register call.

Comment: @Chris Same problem if not sent within a transaction using plain JDBC. As far as I know, EclipseLink's DCN support is only for cache invalidation, but I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for commit indicates that any pending changes should be written and committed to db.

So my guess would be that there is something else which is not part of the above snippet that is taking the 15 minutes before the commit() is invoked. You could test that out.

A potential work around (if the issue is not due to delay in the persistence framework level and is identified as an issue with the oracle-driver or equivalent), would be to invoke the procedure directly instead.

Comment: The same problem exists, if the registration is done outside a transaction via plain JDBC

Comment: 1.) So it works fine within a transaction using plain jdbc ?  2.) but not so if its within a transaction managed by container ? 3.) Did you try invoking the procedure from JDBC with or without transaction ? 4.) Here is a [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2329085?tstart=0) that may help

Comment: It works fine, if I don't register a remote callback (which uses a TCP connection to my machine created by the server) but a callback to a PL/SQL procedure residing locally on the server. In the latter case, the PL/SQL procedure gets called instantly, while in the first case, it takes up to 15 minutes for the callback to be sent.